# Text alignment issues in CSS-generated strip

Tags: css, text, alignment, vertical-alignment

I've created a simple strip on which a text content is placed, which looks like image below.[image: Strip showing text above it]

and the CSS for the same is:

```
.strip {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 6em;
    height: 2em;
    background: #090909;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is to get Text in the middle of the strip, both horizontally and vertically, while `text-align: center` helps me to attain horizontal centering of text. I can't get the text vertically centered. Note that my mark is plain `<div class="strip">12345678</div>` and I'm not willing to use any `span` within that `div`. And want to keep markup as clean as possible. How can I attain this behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add line-height equal to the height of the div. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/VRBrr/2/

```
line-height:2em;
```

Comment: Fair enough. I was searching such thing as well. Thanks

Comment: I played with different values of `line-height` but didn't worked. Why having line-height same as height of strip worked?

Comment: because it sets the height of the content line leaving equal spacing above and below the content, hence vertically aligning the text in middle. Also note that this solution will only work if you have a single line content.